# Error al ACTUALIZAR Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

estoy tratando de actualizar un registro en la base de datos y me da este error:

```html
<h1>A Database Error Occurred</h1>
<p>Error Number: 1062</p>
<p>Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'</p>
<p>UPDATE `compra` SET `compra_id` = '1', `fecha_compra` = '2018-06-10 00:00:00', `cantidad` = 29, `id_tarjeta` = '1', `cantidad_comprada` = '30'</p>
<p>Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/GestoAG/system/database/DB_driver.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 691</p>
```

Estoy usando CodeIgniter como framework, y este es mi fragmento código:

```
$compra_to_update = $this->get_compra_to_update($ingreso ['id_tarjeta']);
$compra_to_update[0]['cantidad'] = $compra_to_update[0]['cantidad'] - $ingreso['cantidad_tarjetas'];
if (empty ($ingreso_id)) {
            try {
                $this->db->insert(self::TABLE_NAME, $ingreso);
                $this->db->insert_id();
                $this->db->update(self::COMPRA_TABLE, $compra_to_update[0]);
                $re = $this->db->update(self::STADISTIC_TABLE, $historico_array[0]);
                return $re ? "OK" : "F";
            } catch (Exception $ex) {
                return $ex->getMessage();
            }
}
```

Lo que no entiendo es que si lo estoy haciendo de la misma manera que al actualizar la tabla STADISTIC_TABLE (en el código está), entonces porque me da ese error??, será algo en la base de datos MySQL???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu update

```
UPDATE `compra` 
SET `compra_id` = '1',
    `fecha_compra` = '2018-06-10 00:00:00',
    `cantidad` = 29,
    `id_tarjeta` = '1',
    `cantidad_comprada` = '30'
```

no tiene cláusula `WHERE`, así que está intentando actualizar TODAS las filas de la tabla. Obviamente no puedes poner a más de una la misma PK.

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo que hice fue agregar delante de la línea:
$this->db->update(self::COMPRA_TABLE, $compra_to_update[0]);
la siguiente línea:
$this->db->where('compra_id',compra_to_update[0]['compra_id'])
Saludos

Comment: ¿Puedes marcar la respuesta como *aceptada*? Así la pregunta quedará marcada como respondida :)

Comment: donde se hace eso?, soy nuevo en el sitio...:-(

Comment: no puedo votar porque aún no tengo suficiente reputación, si es a eso a lo que usted se refiere

Comment: ya descubrí como era, saludos y gracias por todo